# How to create an android share intent that can work with all clients?

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, share

Hi I'm working on app and I want to publish a tweet with a photo using a Share intent.
First I search and I found an intent that works with the official client, and what I want is that my app work with all clients.

Here it's my code:

```
    String message = "Here goes my message";
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/screenshot.jpeg");
    try {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setClassName(getApplicationContext(),findTwitterClient().getPackage());
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        startActivity(sharingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("In Exception", "Comes here");

        //This also opens a dialog that

    }
```

Also I have the following function to know what client is installed on the device.

```
public Intent findTwitterClient() {
    final String[] twitterApps = {
            // package // name - nb installs (thousands)
            "com.twitter.android", // official - 10 000
            "com.twidroid", // twidroyd - 5 000
            "com.handmark.tweetcaster", // Tweecaster - 5 000
            "com.thedeck.android" /* TweetDeck - 5 000*/ };
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent();
    tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < twitterApps.length; i++) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
            String p = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (p != null && p.startsWith(twitterApps[i])) {
                tweetIntent.setPackage(p);
                return tweetIntent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee that you can share with all Twitter clients. Intents are a sort of interface between applications. Each client decides for itself which intents it supports handling. You could easily imagine a custom Twitter client that doesn't handle any intents other than the main launch one.

Comment: yee, but I think that the most popular clients can accept intents. I am talking about clients like twidroid, tweecster or tweetdeck

Answer (score 1):

If your URL starts with "http://twitter.com", Android will ask the user what app should the tweet be opened with. Pretty much any app that registers for that URL scheme can be used.

Comment: I don't understand you, about what URL are you talking me?

Comment: Ok, I get it. You want a photo to be tweeted with any Twitter client. I thought you have a tweet with a photo and have it display with any client. Since it's only an image, you can only do a Share intent. I can't find any code on how to get the apps registered for a certain URL scheme.